# Why is my browser firing the requests in the picture below regularly?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor

[image]

The backend server is a node application. I am not able to understand why these requests are being fired and how can I fix this?

I have worked on node applications before and have never faced any issue. The only difference that I can think of is this line : 
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(Meteor.bindEnvironment(app));

I don't fully understand the above line and its impact, I suspect this has something to do with the current network calls. Any pointers in any direction would be helpful.

***UPDATE***: I am using meteor as a wrapper for my project and suspect that meteor has some package which is causing this long polling to occur. However, I am not able to turn it off. Which meteor package should I remove to disable these calls.

Comment: Look in the Chrome dev tools `network` tab or the dev tools of which ever browser you are using. There should be a request and a response there. Where is it sending the http request to?

Comment: I think you should add more details if you want know why this action being triggered instead of asking other developers to comment if we need more info :D